# Magento WordPress Integration : Database Error

Tags: magento-1.9, wordpress

I want to integrate 'WordPress Integration' plugin. 
The extenstion link is,
https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/wordpress-integration-1.html

My Magento ver. 1.9.0.0 and wordpress version is 4.6.1. I have installed this extenstion in the local magento setup but after installation I'm getting following message,

> Database Error : Error establishing a database connection. You can
>   confirm your WordPress database details by opening the file
>   wp-config.php, which is in your WordPress root directory.

can you please help me to resolve this error ?

Thanks

Comment: Looks like you did not configure the extension. You have to enter the wordpress database credentials.

Comment: As mentioned in error, edit your wp-config.php file located in wordpress root folder to add database credentials and try to check.

Comment: @Rakesh:  I have almost the same error in  Magento 1.9.4.X but did not use any Wordpress plugin. any help will be appreciated https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/301846/magento1-9-4-x-i-have-getting-database-error-in-my-development-server?noredirect=1#comment435200_301846